# Can I replace the word "where" (conjunction) with "by which" phrase?

Tags: conjunctions

Can I replace the word "where" (conjunction) with "by which" phrase?

For example:

> "Ell-SE is the site **by which** I come to ask on my doubts in English
>   language issues".

another example:

> This is the building **by which** the prime-minister lives.

Comment: No, "by which" means "by means of which", you can use "on which" for the site and "in which"  for the building.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "which" and make a relative clause but the preposition is wrong. Since "where" refers to a place, a site, in your sentence, you can say "on which".By which refers to a tool (by means of which).

> It is a site on which/where I can ask about English.